# Difference between parameters and system of parameters in a local commutative ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

Can you please tell me the difference between the 'parameters' and the 'system of parameters' of a commutative local ring? Also, is there any relation between  parameters and associated primes of the ring?

Comment: I believe by a parameter ideal some people refer to an ideal generated by part of a system of parameter. Their associated primes do not need to be minimal unless one is in a "nice" ring.

Comment: See parameters  as written in my notes ( used in Tight closure  and its applications) is a  set of elements $x_1,x_2......x_i$ such that $ht(x_1...x_t) = t $ for t<i . So is there any relation of such elements with associated primes ? @Youngsu  do you mean an excellent ring  by " nice"?

Comment: Such as Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: @Youngsu For me, and [not only for me](http://people.reed.edu/~iswanson/HeinzerSwanson.pdf), a parameter ideal is generated by a system of parameters.

Comment: @user26857 I would probably follow the definition you quoted. However, my point was that there are some authors who use the term differently. For instance, see Definition 2.8 and below of Tight closures of parameter ideals by Karen Smith.